# Why does moderator never reply?

Tags: discussion, moderators

Why did I get a question from moderator and never get any reply even after I answer it?

Answer (score 3):

We didn't reply because we didn't have much to say. You were clearly unhappy with a number of aspects of the site and we didn't see much point in debating that.